# Change the #formatter of a field when printing it in a tpl.php file

Tags: theming

In my **node.tpl.php** I have used KPR on a field. I notice that is has a lot of options like `['#formatter']`. I would like to change these options when I print the field out in my **node.tpl.php** file.

How can I do this?

I have tried `<?php print render($content['field_paragraph']['#formatter'] = 'header'); ?>`
But it just prints out the words "header".

The field I am using is an entity field (from the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module). I have also created a custom entity view mode (called "header") using the [Entity View Mode](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) module. So changing `#formatter`, should cause it to display with my custom view mode.

I know I can do this in the UI, but I am repeating fields on the page with different view modes, which is something the UI doesn't do (and I don't want to use Display Suit, as it doesn't suit my use case).

---

**Edit**

After digging around, the view mode is not stored in ['#formatter'] but 
`[0]['entity']['paragraphs_item'][5]['#view_mode']`

However, I'd imagine the process of changing `#view_mode` would be the same as changing `#formatter`.